# Conditionally Executing Part of an build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

The following is a fragment of `build.sbt`, that I comment out when I want to debug an individual test.

```
// *** Uncomment These Two Lines If you are debugging individual Test ***

//fork in Test := false

//parallelExecution in Test := false
```

What I would like to do is instead of manually commenting in/out the above fragment, is to run the above condition depending on the environment value I specify to `sbt` (for example `"test-only -Dindividual_test=true"`). This way, I can write various test and integrated run configurations from an IDE.

I know if we left it like this, some day, a developer will push the change with this left undocumented.

Is this something we need to do in `build.scala` instead?

Or is there an alternate way of achieving this?

Comment: When you debug your test in IDE(e.g. Intellij IDEA) you don't need to use sbt. Or clarify your question if your use case is defferent.

Comment: Agree, most tests do not require us to run the sbt, but in this specific test case we need to run the test as a web server and we are issuing an sbt task (actually activator in our case).

Answer (score 2):

You could create an individual setting key which you can change in the interactive session:

build.sbt

```
val individualTest = Def.settingKey[Boolean]("Whether to run tests individually")

individualTest := false // individualTest is a setting like every other

fork in Test := !individualTest.value

parallelExecution in Test := !individualTest.value
```

Now in your session, you can just switch `individualTest` interactively:

```
> set individualTest := true
> testOnly
// fork in Test is false
// parallelExcecution is false
> set individualTest := false
// fork in Test is true
// parallelExcecution is true
```

If you want to run this from the command line, put each individual sbt command in quotes:

```
sbt 'set individualTest := true' 'testOnly myTest'
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It did answer half of the puzzle. Now I am trying to figure out how to set this value from the command line, which is the  other half of the question. For example, "activator -DinvidualTest=true test" does not work. Reading the sbt launcher document, but it is not clear yet to me.

Comment: -D was not a good option so I tried 

activator 'set individualTest := true' test-only myTest

Will cause still an error

Comment: You should be able to use System.getProperty(), e.g., individualTest = System.getProperty("individualTest", "false")